# Linux command to retrieve desired lines

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have data in the following form (stored in file1.txt):

```
<http://stackoverflow> <isA> "website".
<website> <nameIs> <http://stackoverflow>.
```

Now using grep I want to retrieve the lines where "http://stackoverflow" occurs as the first string i.e. if I split the lines on spaces then http://stackoverflow should be the first string.

Based on this my output should be:

```
<http://stackoverflow> <isA> "website".
```

Is it possible to do so using grep or any other linux command. Because if I use: grep http://stackoverflow file1.txt, then I get the output:

```
<http://stackoverflow> <isA> "website".
<website> <nameIs> <http://stackoverflow>.
```

i.e. I get both the lines (whereas my desirable output should contain just the first line of file1.txt):

Comment: With "^" you search for the beginning of the line. Try : `grep "^<http://stackoverflow" file1.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a few lines like these in a file called t0:

```
<http://stackoverflow> <isA> "website".
yes <http://stackoverflow> <isA> "website".
<website> <nameIs> <http://stackoverflow>.
```

This command can do the trick. Notice space after the site:

```
grep "^<http://stackoverflow> " t0
Result:
<http://stackoverflow> <isA> "website".
```

If you choose to use `awk`, you can write something like this:

```
awk '{ if($1 == "<http://stackoverflow>") {print $0} }' t0
```

`awk` is splitting by space and then checking if first item in the split is `<http://stackoverflow>`. If so, print the entire line represented by `$0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
grep ^http://stackoverflow file1.txt
```

`^` matches the beginning of a line

Answer (score 1):

```
grep ^\<http://stackoverflow file1.txt
```

`^` matches the beginning of a line
`\` to match the escape character `<`

Answer (score 0):

simple use head or tail comamnd

```
head -1 file1.txt
```

or

```
tail -1 file1.txt
```

this solution offered based on your post.